# Gracefully ending a thread that's waiting on a blocking queue

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I'm having an issue with a multi-threaded server I'm building as an academic exercise, more specifically with getting a connection to close down gracefully.

Each connection is managed by a Session class.  This class maintains 2 threads for the connection, a DownstreamThread and an UpstreamThread.

The UpstreamThread blocks on the client socket and encodes all incoming strings into messages to be passed up to another layer to deal with.  The DownstreamThread blocks on a BlockingQueue into which messages for the client are inserted.  When there's a message on the queue, the Downstream thread takes the message off the queue, turns it into a string and sends it to the client. In the final system, an application layer will act on incoming messages and push outgoing messages down to the server to send to the appropriate client, but for now I just have a simple application that sleeps for a second on an incoming message before echoing it back as an outgoing message with a timestamp appended.

The problem I'm having is getting the whole thing to shut down gracefully when the client disconnects.  The first issue I'm contending with is a normal disconnect, where the client lets the server know that it's ending the connection with a QUIT command.  The basic pseudocode is:

```
while (!quitting) {
    inputString = socket.readLine () // blocks
    if (inputString != "QUIT") {
        // forward the message upstream
        server.acceptMessage (inputString);
    } else {
        // Do cleanup
        quitting = true;
        socket.close ();
    }
}
```

The upstream thread's main loop looks at the input string.  If it's QUIT the thread sets a flag to say that the client has ended communications and exits the loop.  This leads to the upstream thread shutting down nicely.

The downstream thread's main loop waits for messages in the BlockingQueue for as long as the connection closing flag isn't set.  When it is, the downstream thread is also supposed to terminate.  However, it doesn't, it just sits there waiting.  Its psuedocode looks like this:

```
while (!quitting) {
    outputMessage = messageQueue.take (); // blocks
    sendMessageToClient (outputMessage);
}
```

When I tested this, I noticed that when the client quit, the upstream thread shut down, but the downstream thread didn't.

After a bit of head scratching, I realised that the downstream thread is still blocking on the BlockingQueue waiting for an incoming message that will never come.  The upstream thread doesn't forward the QUIT message any further up the chain.

How can I make the downstream thread shut down gracefully?  The first idea that sprang to mind was setting a timeout on the take() call.  I'm not too keen on this idea though, because whatever value you select, it's bound to be not entirely satisfactory.  Either it's too long and a zombie thread sits there for a long time before shutting down, or it's too short and connections that have idled for a few minutes but are still valid will be killed.  I did think of sending the QUIT message up the chain, but that requires it to make a full round trip to the server, then the application, then back down to the server again and finally to the session.  This doesn't seem like an elegant solution either.

I did look at the documentation for Thread.stop() but that's apparently deprecated because it never worked properly anyway, so that looks like it's not really an option either.  Another idea I had was to force an exception to be triggered in the downstream thread somehow and let it clean up in its finally block, but this strikes me as a horrible and kludgey idea.

I feel that both threads should be able to gracefully shutdown on their own, but I also suspect that if one thread ends it must also signal the other thread to end in a more proactive way than simply setting a flag for the other thread to check.  As I'm still not very experienced with Java, I'm rather out of ideas at this point.  If anyone has any advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

For the sake of completeness, I've included the real code for the Session class below, though I believe the pseudocode snippets above cover the relevant parts of the problem.  The full class is about 250 lines.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

/**
 * Session class
 * 
 * A session manages the individual connection between a client and the server. 
 * It accepts input from the client and sends output to the client over the 
 * provided socket.
 * 
 */
public class Session {
    private Socket              clientSocket    = null;
    private Server              server          = null;
    private Integer             sessionId       = 0;
    private DownstreamThread    downstream      = null;
    private UpstreamThread      upstream        = null;
    private boolean             sessionEnding   = false;

    /**
     * This thread handles waiting for messages from the server and sending
     * them to the client
     */
    private class DownstreamThread implements Runnable {
        private BlockingQueue<DownstreamMessage>    incomingMessages    = null;
        private OutputStreamWriter                  streamWriter        = null;
        private Session                             outer               = null;

        @Override
        public void run () {
            DownstreamMessage message;
            Thread.currentThread ().setName ("DownstreamThread_" + outer.getId ());

            try {
                // Send connect message
                this.sendMessageToClient ("Hello, you are client " + outer.getId ());

                while (!outer.sessionEnding) {
                    message = this.incomingMessages.take ();
                    this.sendMessageToClient (message.getPayload ());
                }

                // Send disconnect message
                this.sendMessageToClient ("Goodbye, client " + getId ());

            } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger (DownstreamThread.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage (), ex);
            } finally {
                this.terminate ();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Add a message to the downstream queue
         * 
         * @param message
         * @return
         * @throws InterruptedException 
         */
        public DownstreamThread acceptMessage (DownstreamMessage message) throws InterruptedException {
            if (!outer.sessionEnding) {
                this.incomingMessages.put (message);
            }

            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Send the given message to the client
         * 
         * @param message
         * @throws IOException 
         */
        private DownstreamThread sendMessageToClient (CharSequence message) throws IOException {
            OutputStreamWriter osw;
            // Output to client
            if (null != (osw = this.getStreamWriter ())) {
                osw.write ((String) message);
                osw.write ("\r\n");
                osw.flush ();
            }

            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Perform session cleanup
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        private DownstreamThread terminate () {
            try {
                this.streamWriter.close ();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger (DownstreamThread.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage (), ex);
            }
            this.streamWriter   = null;

            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Get an output stream writer, initialize it if it's not active
         * 
         * @return A configured OutputStreamWriter object
         * @throws IOException 
         */
        private OutputStreamWriter getStreamWriter () throws IOException {
            if ((null == this.streamWriter) 
            && (!outer.sessionEnding)) {
                BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream (outer.clientSocket.getOutputStream ());
                this.streamWriter       = new OutputStreamWriter (os, "UTF8");
            }

            return this.streamWriter;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param outer 
         */
        public DownstreamThread (Session outer) {
            this.outer              = outer;
            this.incomingMessages   = new LinkedBlockingQueue ();
            System.out.println ("Class " + this.getClass () + " created");
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread handles waiting for client input and sending it upstream
     */
    private class UpstreamThread implements Runnable {
        private Session outer   = null;

        @Override
        public void run () {
            StringBuffer    inputBuffer = new StringBuffer ();
            BufferedReader  inReader;

            Thread.currentThread ().setName ("UpstreamThread_" + outer.getId ());

            try {
                inReader    = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (outer.clientSocket.getInputStream (), "UTF8"));

                while (!outer.sessionEnding) {
                    // Read whatever was in the input buffer
                    inputBuffer.delete (0, inputBuffer.length ());
                    inputBuffer.append (inReader.readLine ());
                    System.out.println ("Input message was: " + inputBuffer);

                    if (!inputBuffer.toString ().equals ("QUIT")) {
                        // Forward the message up the chain to the Server
                        outer.server.acceptMessage (new UpstreamMessage (sessionId, inputBuffer.toString ()));
                    } else {
                        // End the session
                        outer.sessionEnding = true;
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                Logger.getLogger (Session.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage (), e);
            } finally {
                outer.terminate ();
                outer.server.deleteSession (outer.getId ());
            }
        }

        /**
         * Class constructor
         * 
         * The Core Java volume 1 book said that a constructor such as this 
         * should be implicitly created, but that doesn't seem to be the case!
         * 
         * @param outer 
         */
        public UpstreamThread (Session outer) {
            this.outer  = outer;
            System.out.println ("Class " + this.getClass () + " created");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start the session threads
     */
    public void run () //throws InterruptedException 
    {
        Thread upThread     = new Thread (this.upstream);
        Thread downThread   = new Thread (this.downstream);

        upThread.start ();
        downThread.start ();
    }

    /**
     * Accept a message to send to the client
     * 
     * @param message
     * @return
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public Session acceptMessage (DownstreamMessage message) throws InterruptedException {
        this.downstream.acceptMessage (message);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Accept a message to send to the client
     * 
     * @param message
     * @return
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public Session acceptMessage (String message) throws InterruptedException {
        return this.acceptMessage (new DownstreamMessage (this.getId (), message));
    }

    /**
     * Terminate the client connection
     */
    private void terminate () {
        try {
            this.clientSocket.close ();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger (Session.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage (), e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get this Session's ID
     * 
     * @return The ID of this session
     */
    public Integer getId () {
        return this.sessionId;
    }

    /**
     * Session constructor
     * 
     * @param owner The Server object that owns this session
     * @param sessionId The unique ID this session will be given
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public Session (Server owner, Socket clientSocket, Integer sessionId) throws IOException {

        this.server         = owner;
        this.clientSocket   = clientSocket;
        this.sessionId      = sessionId;
        this.upstream       = new UpstreamThread (this);
        this.downstream     = new DownstreamThread (this);

        System.out.println ("Class " + this.getClass () + " created");
        System.out.println ("Session ID is " + this.sessionId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `Thread.stop` use `Thread.interrupt`. That will cause the `take` method to throw an `InterruptedException` which you can use to know that you should shut down.

Comment: I did think of that, but isn't forcing something to throw an exception as part of normal shutdown a bit of a kludge?

Comment: No, this is how it's designed to work. Otherwise, every method that could be interrupted would have to return a special interrupted value. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html for more information.

Comment: I don't know much about Java, but what will happen when you call `Thread.interrupt` and we are not in blocking `take` method? I think Interruption won't be raised and we have to check `Thread.isInterrupted` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just create "fake" quit message instead of setting `outer.sessionEnding` to true when "QUIT" appears. Putting this fake message in queue will wake the DownstreamThread and you can end it. In that case you can even eliminate this sessionEnding variable.

In pseudo code this could look like this:

```
while (true) {
    outputMessage = messageQueue.take (); // blocks
    if (QUIT == outputMessage)
        break
    sendMessageToClient (outputMessage);
}
```